# Is it possible to write a log string based on RewriteRule?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a rewrite rule to look for things like `-d+` in the querystring and other common exploit attempts[1](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-1823) [2](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/06/plesk-0-day-remote-vulnerability-in-the-wild.html).

I'm using `[F]` to cause the attempt to be forbidden, but I'd like to log a message like "IP 1.2.3.4 attempted -d+ hack".

Is this possible?

Comment: You could redirect internally to a _script_ that answers with 403 forbidden, and does the logging itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite to a script that logs the attempt for you

`RewriteRule ^exploit-attempt... /logger.php?exploit=dplus`

Comment: Thanks to you and @CBroe for coming up with this at the same time!